# i am trying to run the following program but when i am running i got a "NameError : name "age" is not defined"

Tags: python-3.x, class, nameerror

[this is code snippet help me out pls i am new to programming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUpiJ.jpg)

```
class person():
        def __init__(self,initialAge):
            self.age = 0
            #self.initialAge = 0

            if(initialAge < 0):
                print("Age is not valid")
            else:
                self.age = initialAge

        def amIold(self):
            if(age < 13):
                print("You are young")
            elif(age >= 13 and age < 18):
                print("You are teenage")
            else:
                print("You are old")

        def yearPasses(self):
            global age
            age += 1
```

guys this is a image link pls check for more clarifications

Answer (score 1):

This method:

```
def yearPasses(self):
    global age
    age += 1
```

Should be accessing the `age` attribute through `self`, since it's an instance attribute, and not a global variable:

```
def yearPasses(self):
    self.age += 1
```

You also need to use the same way in the `amIold` method:

```
def amIold(self):
    if(self.age < 13):
        print("You are young")
    elif(self.age >= 13 and self.age < 18):
        print("You are teenage")
    else:
        print("You are old")
```

Also there is no need to use paranthesis on if-statements `if age < 13:`

Comment: The same goes for all occurrences of `age` in the `amIold` method.

Comment: @crater2150 Right!

Comment: @shubhamshukla Impossible to know what's the issue.

Comment: @shubhamshukla You need to fix the `amIold` method also like I've shown, and all of the methods need to take `self` as the first parameter.